# iPhone apps must support the 4-inch display

Tags: ios, app-store, retina-display

Got this news through Apple Developer News RSS -- https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013b -- which says iPhone apps must support the 4-inch display. So now I have to update my app for 4-inch displays and also the images should be retina images.

I'm using some images which are not retina (2x) but still look good.

Will they reject my app if *all* images are not retina? is there any other source for this? I tried to find more information because the news link is not clear.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all images have to be retina images. Apple simply scans the interfaces for images that aren't retina-ready, and will refuse your application if not all images are retina. This process is mostly automated, so it's really unlikely that they would make an exception.

That said, some exceptions may be made for content, but not for the interfaces.