# iPhone 4-inch screens - must they now be supported?

Tags: ios, app-store, retina-display

When developing an app for the iOS platform - if I want my app to only support the iPhone 3.5inch screen (i.e. not the iPhone 5) - and have letterboxing appear on the iPhone 5 when run, I can see how this is done through Xcode, by deleting the Default-568h@2x.png file.

However, when you upload an app to the AppStore, it comes back with a warning and a screenshot issue when you have no picture in the Retina 4-inch section.

So my question is, do developers now have to support Retina 4-inch screens when uploading apps for iPhone products, or is there a way to release an app now which on iPhone devices shows up letterboxed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Would questions about App Store approval be appropriate for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131388)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone apps must support the 4-inch display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657202/iphone-apps-must-support-the-4-inch-display)

Comment: Oops, I meant to link [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Launch image really necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552348/iphone-5-optimization-requirement-launch-image-really-necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must support the 4" screen.

> Starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. Learn about preparing your apps by reviewing the

Source: https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013b